# UNION ALL difficulties in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having an issue with right paranthesis when trying to do UNION All query in Oracle SQL.

```
((SELECT DISTINCT call.call_id,
                  call_key_msg.key_msg,
                  Substr(call_key_msg.clm_id, 0, Length(call_key_msg.clm_id) - 4
                  )
                    AS asset,
                  call_clickstream.track_elmnt_desc
                    AS TRACKELEMENT
  FROM   outbound.call,
         outbound.call_key_msg,
         outbound.call_clickstream
  WHERE  call.call_id = call_key_msg.call_id
         AND call_clickstream.call(+) = call.call_id
         AND call.call_id IN ( '1', '2',
                               '3', '4' )
  MINUS
  SELECT DISTINCT call.call_id,
                  call_key_msg.key_msg,
                  Substr(call_key_msg.clm_id, 0, Length(call_key_msg.clm_id) - 4
                  )
                  AS asset,
                  call_clickstream.track_elmnt_desc
                  AS TRACKELEMENT
  FROM   outbound.call,
         outbound.call_key_msg,
         outbound.call_clickstream
  WHERE  call.call_id = call_key_msg.call_id
         AND call_clickstream.call = call.call_id
         AND call_key_msg.key_msg = call_clickstream.key_msg
         AND call.call_id IN ( '1', '2',
                               '3',
                                                   '4' )
  ORDER  BY 3)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT DISTINCT call.call_id,
                  call_key_msg.key_msg,
                  Substr(call_key_msg.clm_id, 0, Length(call_key_msg.clm_id) - 4
                  )
                  AS asset,
                  call_clickstream.track_elmnt_desc
                  AS TRACKELEMENT
  --case when call_clickstream.CLM_ID = 'CLM ID' THEN call_clickstream.PRSNTN_ID 
  --ELSE SUBSTR(call_key_msg.CLM_ID, 0, LENGTH(call_key_msg.CLM_ID) - 4) 
  --END AS asset
  FROM   outbound.call,
         outbound.call_key_msg,
         outbound.call_clickstream
  WHERE  call.call_id = call_key_msg.call_id
         AND call_clickstream.call = call.call_id
         AND call_key_msg.key_msg = call_clickstream.key_msg
         AND call.call_id IN ( '1', '2',
                               '3',
                                                   '4' )
  ORDER  BY 3));
```

Not sure what is wrong here, but I keep getting the error 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis'. I have checked my parantheses, and they seem to line up. Any thoughts? Ignore the weird spacing in the where call.call_id - I just used a SQL formatter and it made it look a little funky just now.

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How would one join this?

Comment: Gordon is suggesting to use the standard ANSI syntax - JOIN. instead of commas and join condition in WHERE clause

Comment: Is that better for performance?

Comment: It is good for redability, and maintanance. Also, I am not sure but try to remove order by and also check for any non-ascii characters in your syntax.

Comment: @mike0494 it will give you the same performance, and won’t fix your syntax error...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I removed the second parenthesis before your first SELECT statement and your very last parenthesis.

```
 (SELECT DISTINCT call.call_id,
                  call_key_msg.key_msg,
                  Substr(call_key_msg.clm_id, 0, Length(call_key_msg.clm_id) - 4
                  )
                    AS asset,
                  call_clickstream.track_elmnt_desc
                    AS TRACKELEMENT
  FROM   outbound.call,
         outbound.call_key_msg,
         outbound.call_clickstream
  WHERE  call.call_id = call_key_msg.call_id
         AND call_clickstream.call(+) = call.call_id
         AND call.call_id IN ( '1', '2',
                               '3', '4' )
  MINUS
  SELECT DISTINCT call.call_id,
                  call_key_msg.key_msg,
                  Substr(call_key_msg.clm_id, 0, Length(call_key_msg.clm_id) - 4
                  )
                  AS asset,
                  call_clickstream.track_elmnt_desc
                  AS TRACKELEMENT
  FROM   outbound.call,
         outbound.call_key_msg,
         outbound.call_clickstream
  WHERE  call.call_id = call_key_msg.call_id
         AND call_clickstream.call = call.call_id
         AND call_key_msg.key_msg = call_clickstream.key_msg
         AND call.call_id IN ( '1', '2',
                               '3',
                                                   '4' )
  ORDER  BY 3)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT DISTINCT call.call_id,
                  call_key_msg.key_msg,
                  Substr(call_key_msg.clm_id, 0, Length(call_key_msg.clm_id) - 4
                  )
                  AS asset,
                  call_clickstream.track_elmnt_desc
                  AS TRACKELEMENT
  --case when call_clickstream.CLM_ID = 'CLM ID' THEN call_clickstream.PRSNTN_ID 
  --ELSE SUBSTR(call_key_msg.CLM_ID, 0, LENGTH(call_key_msg.CLM_ID) - 4) 
  --END AS asset
  FROM   outbound.call,
         outbound.call_key_msg,
         outbound.call_clickstream
  WHERE  call.call_id = call_key_msg.call_id
         AND call_clickstream.call = call.call_id
         AND call_key_msg.key_msg = call_clickstream.key_msg
         AND call.call_id IN ( '1', '2',
                               '3',
                                                   '4' )
  ORDER  BY 3);
```

Comment: I get the same error - An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
(SELECT DISTINCT call.call_id,
                  call_key_msg.key_msg,
                  Substr(call_key_msg.clm_id, 0, Length(call_key_msg.clm_id) - ...

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Do you have a chance to provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have put each of your `union all` branches within parenthesis, presumably to work around the lack of being able to use an order by within a `union all` branch.

You can add `select * from`  to before you parenthesised queries to make it work. See this quick [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=df758fb680c2f0c648444ab3c6fbfd81) which demonstrates your error and the syntax fix.

For your query, it would look like:

```
select * from (SELECT DISTINCT call.call_id,
                  call_key_msg.key_msg,
                  Substr(call_key_msg.clm_id, 0, Length(call_key_msg.clm_id) - 4
                  )
                    AS asset,
                  call_clickstream.track_elmnt_desc
                    AS TRACKELEMENT
  FROM   outbound.call,
         outbound.call_key_msg,
         outbound.call_clickstream
  WHERE  call.call_id = call_key_msg.call_id
         AND call_clickstream.call(+) = call.call_id
         AND call.call_id IN ( '1', '2',
                               '3', '4' )
  MINUS
  SELECT DISTINCT call.call_id,
                  call_key_msg.key_msg,
                  Substr(call_key_msg.clm_id, 0, Length(call_key_msg.clm_id) - 4
                  )
                  AS asset,
                  call_clickstream.track_elmnt_desc
                  AS TRACKELEMENT
  FROM   outbound.call,
         outbound.call_key_msg,
         outbound.call_clickstream
  WHERE  call.call_id = call_key_msg.call_id
         AND call_clickstream.call = call.call_id
         AND call_key_msg.key_msg = call_clickstream.key_msg
         AND call.call_id IN ( '1', '2',
                               '3',
                                                   '4' )
  ORDER  BY 3)
 UNION ALL
select * from 
 (SELECT DISTINCT call.call_id,
                  call_key_msg.key_msg,
                  Substr(call_key_msg.clm_id, 0, Length(call_key_msg.clm_id) - 4
                  )
                  AS asset,
                  call_clickstream.track_elmnt_desc
                  AS TRACKELEMENT
  --case when call_clickstream.CLM_ID = 'CLM ID' THEN call_clickstream.PRSNTN_ID 
  --ELSE SUBSTR(call_key_msg.CLM_ID, 0, LENGTH(call_key_msg.CLM_ID) - 4) 
  --END AS asset
  FROM   outbound.call,
         outbound.call_key_msg,
         outbound.call_clickstream
  WHERE  call.call_id = call_key_msg.call_id
         AND call_clickstream.call = call.call_id
         AND call_key_msg.key_msg = call_clickstream.key_msg
         AND call.call_id IN ( '1', '2',
                               '3',
                                                   '4' )
  ORDER  BY 3);
```

I've taken out the outer most parenthesise as they don't really solve a purpose, but they don't exactly hurt.